# insert some variables value in another variable

Tags: php

when i put `' . $data->items[0]->contentDetails->duration . '` it print a youtube video duration PT2M47S but need 2:47 or 2day 47 minute how can plz codded

Comment: Could you please proof read your question before posting it? Also, what have you tried... where is the error... what is the problem...

Comment: how does `4:47` come out from `PT2M47S`   What is the logic behind it? i get the `:47` but the `:4` And what have you tried?

Comment: @pr1nc3: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Durations

Comment: sorry typing mistake 2:47 i need 2hour 47 minute like this

Comment: The string is for [DateInterval](http://php.net/manual/en/class.dateperiod.php) **P**lus **T**ime 2 **M**in 47 **S**econds, why not use it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PHP's `DateInterval` class supports parsing ISO-8601 duration strings natively:

```
$interval = new DateInterval('PT2M47S');
echo $interval->format('%i:%s');
// 2:47
```

As a function:

```
function convertISODuration(string $isoDuration) {
  $interval = new DateInterval($isoDuration);
  return $interval->format('%i:%s');
}

echo convertISODuration('PT2M47S');
```

See https://eval.in/908515

Comment: when i put ' . $data->items[0]->contentDetails->duration . ' it print a youtube video duration PT2M47S but need 2:47 ot 2day 47 minute

Comment: `PT2M47S` means +2 minutes and 47 seconds. Why are you expecting anything other than that?

Comment: when i put ' . $data->items[0]->contentDetails->duration . ' it print a youtube video duration PT2M47S but need 2:47 or 2day 47 minute  how can plz codded

Comment: I've added a functional version of the my original code, you can use that in your output instead of the literal ISO duration string

Comment: its not always PT2M47S its dynamic every video will be different time dear

Comment: Yes, of course, I understand that. You need to pass your variable to the function instead of a hard-coded string. I can't really help you any further than this.

Comment: just tell me when i write $t how it give me ' . $data->items[0]->contentDetails->duration . ' its value ?